# Corrupted data and protocol-buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to know how does protocol buffers handles corrupted data while parsing stream. Is there any way to know if data has been corrupted.

Does protocol buffer provides any inbuilt mechanism for data integrity check?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

None whatsoever. While some changes might be detected by causing parse failures, a lot of other changes would not be flagged at all. If you are concerned about integrity, add a separate mechanism for this outside of the serialization layer - presumably a checksum / hash.

Comment: I'm more concerned about any crash or exception.  Will parsing fail in case of corruption of data?

Comment: @user832096 it *might*, but it might not; it depends exactly on what form the corruption takes. You should not *rely* on it failing to parse to detect an error, as I can think of lots of ways of damaging a stream/file/whatever that would go undetected (except for giving the wrong data); nor should you *rely* on it parsing without error - I can think of lots of subtle ways of corrupting a stream/file/etc that would break most serializers.